# tshark : ***MEMORY-ERROR***: [6265]: GSlice: assertion failed: sinfo->n_allocated > 0

Tags: centos

i have `wireshark-1.10.14-7.el7.x86_64` installed when i run tshark i get the error after about 15 to 20 seconds.It works only for few seconds and throws error

There is a red hat Bug 1176967 but to see that red hat subscription is required.How do i solve this in cent OS 7.

command that i am running is :

```
sudo -S stdbuf -o L tshark -Q -B 20 -i eth0                                               \
'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' \
-Y'http.request.method == "GET" && http.request.uri contains "/imagepage/"'   \
-T fields -e http.host -e http.request.uri 2>/dev/null >somefile
```

while searching [here](https://www.techylib.com/en/view/cuttlefishblue/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6_technical_notes_red_hat_customer) i found this but how do i set this value of `G_SLICE=always_malloc`.i don't know if this would help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting the following variable (worked for me)

```
export G_SLICE=always-malloc evolution
```

see more [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/1169694).

Comment: had this while sniffing multipart stuff. looks like this works